# build a complicated dict by using dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

Here is a question for python programming.

I am trying to build a dict by importing data from excel for analyzing.

my structure of the dictionary is:

```
dict = { sheet_name : 
                  {label_name1 : [['datatype'],['','',some_data.....]],      
                   label_name2 : [['datatype'],['','',some_data.....]],
                   ...
                  }
         sheet_name1 :
                  {label_name3 : [['datatype'],['','',some_data.....]],      
                   label_name4 : [['datatype'],['','',some_data.....]],
                   ...
                  }
       }
```

now i use the xlrd to process reading data.

```
file = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)

table_names = file.sheet_names()    

label = sum([file.sheet_by_name(names).row_values(0) for names in
         table_names], [])

SHEET_DICT = {names: {labels: [['unknown_datatype'], 
                               file.sheet_by_name(names)\
                                   .col_values(i for i \
                                   in file.sheet_by_name(names).ncols))]
                       for labels in label}               
              for names in table_names }
```

i got an error message:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):    File "C:/Users/panze/PycharmProjects/Harvest/main.py", line 92, in 
> >         test = read_excel(EXCELFILE)    File "C:/Users/panze/PycharmProjects/Harvest/main.py", line 73, in
> >     read_excel
> >         for names in table_names }    File "C:/Users/panze/PycharmProjects/Harvest/main.py", line 73, in
> >     
> >         for names in table_names }    File "C:/Users/panze/PycharmProjects/Harvest/main.py", line 72, in
> >     
> >         for label in labels}
>
> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

```
> file.sheet_by_name(names).col_values(0) is right 

> file.sheet_by_name(names).col_values(1) is right
```

when i try to use variable instead

```
file.sheet_by_name(names).col_values(i for i in range(29))
```

it is wrong.

however i need it makes iterable so that i can build a right dict.

is there other way to do that?

i really what to use dict comprehension to do this way ...

thanks for your help

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: At a certain point you give up on comprehensions. They ultimately begin to hurt readability and reasoning once they reach a certain size. Unless its just for interest then just do it in a loop or define a function you call in the comprehension.

Comment: I'm not sure what you wanted `col_values(i for i in range(29))` to return. A list of 29 columns, each of which is a list of that column's value in every row? Or something different?

Comment: yes, it is each value in every  col

Comment: What is the return value of the method `ncols`? If it is just an integer, the interpeter sees something like `for i in 29`, which is wrong code, because `29` is not an iterable object...

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Sheet.col_values):

```
col_values(colx, start_rowx=0, end_rowx=None)
```

> Returns a slice of the values of the cells in the given column.

So, you don't pass it an iterable like `i for i in range(29)` (which, by the way, is just a more verbose and slower way to get the same values as just `range(29)`), you pass it a column number, start row, and end row.

If you want to get a list of column 0, column 1, column 2, etc., you can do that like this:

```
[file.sheet_by_name(names).col_values(i) for i in range(29)]
```

If you're trying to get a list of column 0, column 1, etc. just for a specific row, you can instead use the `row_values` function, passing the row number and then the start and end column.